# SQL Server : how to pivot a three column table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this

[image]

and I want a result like this,

[image]

Is pivot the way to do that? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've designed your table is not going to give you an exact match of the pivot you have provided. Even as a pivot table your columns must match the same data type. Your example is mixing text and numbers into the same column from multiple columns. 
If you are wanting to get a report similar to this pivot table, then it would be up to what ever reporting tool you are using to design and provide that result. The SQL Query would select the data for you to build the report off of but it wouldn't be the finished state. 
For example if you are using SSRS you would use a matrix or table element and then custom set the fields to populate how you want. But you won't be able to mix in the grade and year columns into the letter grade column in a SQL query itself. -At least not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

npeach is right what you are trying to achieve will be quite impossible with the current design of your table as you are mixing numbers and strings . Even when developing SSRS with current design will give headaches. But You can get this result if that helps you

```
Name    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005
   aaa  5       10      15      20      25      30
   bbb  35      40      45      50      55      60

select * 
from 
(
  select  [Name],[Year],[Grade]
  from MyGrade

) a
pivot
(
  avg([Grade])
  for [Year] in ([2000],[2001],[2002],[2003],[2004],[2005])
) piv;
```

DB Code

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Grade]    Script Date: 8/12/2016 12:40:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Grade](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Year] [int] NULL,
    [letter] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Grade] [int]( NULL

) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (1, N'aaa', 2000, N'5', N'a')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (2, N'aaa', 2001, N'10', N'b')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (3, N'aaa', 2002, N'15', N'c')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (4, N'aaa', 2003, N'20', N'd')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (5, N'aaa', 2004, N'25', N'e')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (6, N'aaa', 2005, N'30', N'f')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (7, N'bbb', 2000, N'35', N'a')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (8, N'bbb', 2001, N'40', N'b')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (9, N'bbb', 2002, N'45', N'c')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (10, N'bbb', 2003, N'50', N'd')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (11, N'bbb', 2004, N'55', N'e')
INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ([Id], [Name], [Year], [Grade], [letter]) VALUES (12, N'bbb', 2005, N'60', N'f')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Grade] OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

The first three line should be combine together and treat as header, than you can use PIVOT, If the count of letter may be changed, you should use dynamic script，
it is a sample:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tt') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #tt
     CREATE TABLE #tt(NAME varchar(5),letter CHAR(1),YEAR int,grade int)
     INSERT INTO #tt
         SELECT 'aaa','a',2000,5 UNION
         SELECT 'aaa','b',2001,10 UNION
         SELECT 'aaa','c',2002,15 UNION
         SELECT 'aaa','d',2003,20 UNION
         SELECT 'aaa','e',2004,25 UNION
         SELECT 'aaa','f',2005,30 UNION
         SELECT 'bbb','a',2000,10 UNION
         SELECT 'bbb','b',2001,20 UNION
         SELECT 'bbb','c',2002,30 UNION
         SELECT 'bbb','d',2003,40 UNION
         SELECT 'bbb','e',2004,50 UNION
         SELECT 'bbb','f',2005,60
         DECLARE @col VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(max)
         SELECT @col=ISNULL(@col+',[','[')+'letter/'+letter+'/'+LTRIM(year)+']' FROM #tt GROUP BY letter,YEAR

         SET @sql='
            SELECT * FROM (
              SELECT Name,''letter/''+letter+''/''+LTRIM(year) AS letter,grade FROM #tt 
            ) AS t PIVOT(MAX(grade) FOR letter IN ('+@col+')) p'

         EXEC(@sql)
```

```
Name  letter/a/2000 letter/b/2001 letter/c/2002 letter/d/2003 letter/e/2004 letter/f/2005
----- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------
aaa   5             10            15            20            25            30
bbb   10            20            30            40            50            60
```

Comment: I don't think this will make the OP happy, so I can't upvote, but I believe it's also the closest it's possible to get via SQL, so I won't downvote, either. Add some notes at the top about why he can't get what he wants, and I could fully support this.